# UICollectionView remove header after inserting a section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, performbatchupdates

I have a few sections in my `UICollectionViewController`, and only the first one should have a header. How to nicely insert a section at the front while removing the header from the previous first section?

I already set `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` to be `.zero` for non-first sections. And here is what I have so far. It works but the header is noticeably removed AFTER insertion animation is finished. I tried to put them together, but it just didn't work

```
self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({

    self.collectionView?.insertSections([0])
    self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: someIndexPaths)

}, completion: { (_) in

    let context = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext()
    context.invalidateSupplementaryElements(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1)])
    self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout(with: context)

})
```

Comment: Have you tried keeping the first section empty of items so that it's just the header view? Then the second section would be the first one populated with items and you would insert new sections at index `1`. That's if you're trying to fake something like a `tableHeaderView` but in a `UICollectionView` which doesn't have a true equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did in the end, having an empty first section with just the header. Thanks!